# Using xterm.js with addon: term-addon-attach

Tags: javascript, html, xtermjs

I just want to be able to include xterm.js and the addon, and it should work. But I am totally lost on how to import the attach xterm-addon-attach in my `index.html` as a script.

They mention to import the libs via ES6 which give me various errors like: *“Can’t find "`Terminal`" in `xterm.js`”*. I put the import statements in another `.js` file, and sourced that in my HTML code with the `type="module"` attribute, but I get that error.

Wasted a few hours on this, and I’m afraid this is probably simple to do and I’m just missing something simple.

Can anyone help me understand how to get past this and use xterm and the attach addon? Just using xterm alone is fine.

Here’s the `loadxterm.js`:

```js
import { Terminal } from './xterm.js';
//import { AttachAddon } from './xterm-addon-attach.js';

const webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000/websocket");

const terminal = new Terminal();
//const attachAddon = new AttachAddon(webSocket);
//terminal.loadAddon(attachAddon);

terminal.open(document.getElementById('terminal-container'));
terminal.write("hi!")
```

And the `index.html`:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/xterm.css" />
    <script type="module" src="/static/loadxterm.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function getLog() {
        fetch("/run");
      }

      //      window.setInterval(function () {
      //       var elem = document.getElementById("content");
      //      elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
      //  }, 5000);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="javascript:getLog()">Run process!</button>
    <h3>Output</h3>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="terminal-container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @SebastianSimon Fixed the typo and included some code.

Comment: Can you import _anything_ from `"./xterm.js"`, i.e. `import Terminal from './xterm.js';`?

Comment: I get "loadxterm.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './xterm.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

Comment: Then `./xterm.js` is not the file you’re looking for.

Comment: xterm.js currently does not expose ES6 module interfaces (guide is misleading). This should work - load xterm.js with normal script tag, then use `new Terminal(...)`. Same with addons, but with an additional addon namespace, e.g. AttachAddon ctor is behind `new AttachAddon.AttachAddon(...)`.

Comment: @jerch Thank you! I haven't yet tested this, but would you mind putting this as an answer so I can mark it as accepted (after I test it) -- for others to benefit from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of v4 xterm.js does not yet expose ES6 module interfaces in its bundles (planned for v5). The `import` mentioned in the guide is a bit misleading in this regard (dont want to bore you with the details, just this - it addresses Typescript's import, which currently gets transpiled to `require` due to internal project settings). I admit that the guide could be more clear about that.

*Until ES6 exports, what do the bundles actually contain?*

Good old vanilla JS definitions on top level, thus they are meant to work with normal `<script>` tags:

- `xterm.js` Main bundle of the terminal exposing the `Terminal` constructor, e.g. this should work:

  ```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/xterm.js"></script>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const term = new Terminal(...);  // Terminal is now defined
  </script>
  ```
- `xterm-addon-xy.js` Individual addon bundles exposing all addon exports under a separate namespace. The namespace name is the same as the addon constructor, e.g.:

  ```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/xterm-addon-xy.js"></script>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // important: since v4 addons are classes,
    // to load an addon we need an instance
    const addonInstance = new XYAddon.XYAddon(...);
    const otherAddonStuff = XYAddon['something_else_exported_by_the_addon'];
    // load addon
    someTerminalInstance.loadAddon(addonInstance);
  </script>
  ```

In your particular question this should work:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/xterm.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/xterm-addon-attach.js"></script>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
  const term = new Terminal(...);
  const attachAddon = new AttachAddon.AttachAddon(new WebSocket(...), {bidirectional: true});
  term.loadAddon(attachAddon);
</script>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I can't believe how awful incomprehensible the doc not eh xterm GitHub guide is.